# Mostrar resultado de Query MySQL com Echo (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, query, count, echo

Tenho um script em PHP e MySQL que tem uma query responsável por contar quantos registros (clientes) estão inseridos em uma das tabelas do meu banco de dados. Entretanto, eu preciso mostrar a quantidade de registros (clientes) existentes na tabela com o comando echo, mas não sei como fazer. Abaixo está meu código:

```
<?php

    include_once 'conexao.php';

    $sql = $dbcon->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbClientes");

?>
```

Tentei usar `echo $sql;` mas não deu certo.

Comment: echo $sql['COUNT(*)'];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**dados para conexao.php**

```
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="USUARIO";  
$password="SENHA";  
$db = "Nome_DB";
```

- **Com PDO**

  ```
  $dbcon = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);

  $sql = $dbcon->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbClientes");

  $total = $sql->fetchColumn();

  echo $total;
  ```
- **Com mysqli**

  ```
   $dbcon = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $db);

   $sql = $dbcon->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbClientes");

   $row = $sql->fetch_row();

   echo $row[0];
  ```